# How to use Jenkins String Parameter in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We am using Jenkins Pipeline to configure jobs in jenkins. For a bunch of jobs we need user input for which we use parameterised build where user can input parameter values and later we use the values in our .jenkinsfile in sh like

```
 sh "./build-apply.sh ${accountnumber} ${volumename} ${vpcname} services ${snapshotid}"
```

This used to work with

- Jenkins 2.16
- Pipeline 2.3
- Groovy 2.15

However, when I rebuild Jenkins to:

- 2.16 or latest 2.26
- Pipeline 2.5
- Pipeline: Groovy 2.19

The above `sh` stopped working. Error being

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: accountnumber for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Any idea what I am missing? Is the syntax not correct?

For reference full `Jenkinsfile` for reference

```
node {
  // Mark the code checkout 'stage'....


  stage 'Checkout'
  git branch: '****', credentialsId: '***', url: '****'

  stage 'Provision Volume'
  withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: '*****',
                    credentialsId: '****',
                    secretKeyVariable: '*****']]) {
    // Run the terraform build
    env.PATH = "${env.PATH}:/jenkins/terraform"
    sh "./build-apply.sh ${accountnumber} ${volumename} ${vpcname} services ${snapshotid}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you expect `accountnumber`, `volumename`, `vpcname`, and `snapshotid` to come from? Are you running the job with the right parameters?

Comment: These are set as parameters on the job, this job has parameters with these names. So this comes from user input and are set.

Comment: Can you please share those parameters definition from this Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the below code in the pipeline script
node: {

```
stage ('BCCdlVsLib') {
build job: 'BCCdlVsLib', parameters:
[
    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'BINPATH', value: 'BINPATH'], 
    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SOURCEFILE', value: 'SOURCEFILE']
        ]
}
```

In the jobs (BCCdlVsLib) enable the option "this project is parametrized" and enter 2 string parameters job_binpath,job_sourcefile.

Print the variables in the pipeline jobs
echo job_binpath
echo job_sourcefile

After run the pipeline job,will get the below output.
BINPATH
SOURCEFILE